# Unity c# make 3D object as button to move to another scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a main menu, and I want to make the 3D object as a button to move to another scene. The 3D object is jar import from SKETCHUP. Im a newbie thats why im still dont know. can someone give me example code using c#?? the name of the object is JAR. thankyou in advance:)

Comment: You should do your homework before asking these most basic questions. There are lots of free unity tutorials on the internet and you should look them up before trying to do anything serious. Being a new in any area of development doesn't make up for asking silly questions.

Comment: Nice work cutting my answer and pasting it here as comment... you could at least reference me or something.

Comment: Such comments are better left out of answers. It might even result in downvotes in some cases. @Steven did you a favour by appropriately editing your question and yet still leaving the relevant comment to the OP.

Comment: i already did so many research about this, but still my 3D object is not clickable, even Onmousedown has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

1. Apply a [Collider](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Collider.html) on your object (or you could make it with raycast but it's not necessary for menu buttons)
2. Define a `OnMouseDown` or `OnMouseUp` event. By the way, learn to use Unity documentation, it even has what you're looking for in this example: [MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html).

This is the code to handle click event: (taken directly from the provided link)

```
void OnMouseDown () { // or OnMouseUp
    Application.LoadLevel("level name"); // or level index
}
```

I assume you know how to define different scenes so you can reference them at loading. If not, read this for a basic guide on how it's done: [Application.LoadLevel](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html).

Also a note: Unity has a really big community forum on it's own and has lots of active members which have much more experience. But please, do your homework and watch the tutorials and also try to search for your problem before spamming with questions that have already been explained. Nobody likes to help someone who doesn't want to do any effort on it's own.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer MAREMP, but i already try that code a thousand times, but still not working. no error but the object still not clickable, i already add a Box collider. take note, my 3Dobject is import from sketchup, and it is a jar. nothing happen.

Comment: a .jar? isn that like a java-zipped-archive? maybe you need to extract the contents first? or find a better 3D program.. if you need a free 3D tool, checkout Blender 3D